# difference of distance functions in h3_distance function in python h3 geo version 3.x

Tags: h3

I am getting confused by some h3 distance functions.

let's say I am trying to get all the cellID from a base cellID in 1 miles.

I find all the function below from h3 website (https://h3geo.org/docs/3.x/api/traversal/)
and they seems the same to me, the k parameter from them all seems like "steps" instead of distance

```
h3.k_ring(h, k)
h3.k_ring_distances(h, k)
h3.hex_range(h, k)
h3.hex_range_distances(h, k)
h3.hex_ranges(h, k)
h3.hex_ring(h, k)
```

Let's assume my resolution is set to 10, what function should I use and how do I calculate my k value?

Thanks